# Abstracting away asynchronicity/promises in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, synchronous

Suppose I have written a library class:

```
class ComplexThingDoer implements ThingDoer {
  ...
  doComplexThing(arg1, arg2) {
     // lots of complex code here
     return finalResult;
  }
  ...
}
```

And I have made this class available to others, who are using it as intended, completely ignorant of how doComplexThing actually does the complex thing and making use of the finalResult for whatever they're using it for.

Now, suppose I decide that I actually want to reimplement doComplexThing so that instead of synchronously running a lot of complex code here, it makes a request to a specialized server that returns the final result. Or makes a call to a database in which results of the complex thing have been precalculated. Or does one of those things the first time it's called with a particular set of arguments, and caches the result so that the next time it's called with the same arguments it can just return the previously-calculated value.

As far as I can tell, whether I use callbacks, Promises, or async/await, I am screwed - I can't do any of those things without breaking my interface. I have to return a Promise, or accept a callback, or something - there doesn't seem to be any way to just *not return until I have the result*, the way I've always done before. My callers don't care how I'm getting the result; they just want the result.

Am I missing something? Is there in fact a way to "de-promisify" a function so that its caller doesn't have to know that it's performing an asynchronous operation? Should I be pre-emptively writing everything as Promises just in case someday I might want to reimplement it in an asynchronous way (sounds like a terrible idea)?

Thanks!

Comment: Add another function called *doComplexThingAsync* which returns a promise. Then add a *console.warn("this function is deprectaed, use...")* to the old one. Then in a few years delete the old.one...

Comment: I feel like trying to mask an asynchronous operation as being synchronous is just going to make your API harder to understand. I don't think you should make everything a promise either, unless you're *really* confident you might make it async later on. Breaking changes are fine, as long as they're communicated well.

Comment: essentially, you want to know if you can somehow make asynchronous code behave synchronously ... think about that for a second and you'll realise the impossibility of that ... don't be afraid of changing your "complexThing" in the future

Comment: Asynchrony cannot be abstracted with JavaScript's threading model. What you're really asking for is blocking on asynchronous code, which is simply not allowed. On the client (browser, mobile/desktop app), blocking would freeze the UI; on the server (node), blocking would prevent other requests from being handled. Blocking is so bad that it's just not allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you're not missing anything. If you make your function asynchronous, then every caller of it will have to treat it as such and also be asynchronous itself. The result of an asynchronous call will be available *sometime later*, on subsequent iterations of the underlying event loop. There is absolutely no way to block synchronous code to wait for that, because if you block in code the event loop won't advance and the result will never become available.

Switching an interface from synchronous to asynchronous is a breaking change.

Comment: Yeah, that's kinda what my research led me to believe... just figured I'd ask the question explicitly since I couldn't find it answered explicitly. So once there's a Promise anywhere in the call chain, it's got to stay Promises all the way back up. Good to know.